# Formula to search specific cells and output an attached value

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, vlookup

[image: 2]

[image: 1]

The first 8 columns are 8 names and the final column is the likelihood of that combination being selected. I can have up to 3 different names selected.

I am looking for a way by using the Name 1, Name 2, Name 3 method, if I select Amy, then I receive the value of 10.

If I select Amy and Beth, then I receive the value of 1.

This could then apply to if I included 3 names.

Try to use sumifs and if(ands) but could not find a way to make it work.

I suspect I may need to use a vlookup, but if there are any other suggestions they would be much appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What specific problem did you run into?

Comment: There are two tables though?